# Changing width directly vs changing width CSS Custom Property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue with expanding side panel width in JavaScript:

I need to resize it on `mousemove` event but visual performance of changing width (like `el.style.width = value`) is far more better than changing custom property (like `style.setProperty('--side-panel-width, value)`) - Actually, the second one is freezing :(

However, I want to change Custom Property, because 2 other panels positioning are depending on this Custom Property value:

```
.other-panel {
  left: calc(var(--side-panel-width) + var(--offset));
}
```

My `mousemove` event handler code (simplified):

```
    onMouseMove(e) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() =>
        const parent = this.$refs.resize.parentNode;
        const dx = this.size - e.x;
        this.size = e.x;

        const value = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(parent, '').width) + dx);

        parent.style.width = value + 'px'; // CHANGE WIDTH DIRECTLY
        // this.app.style.setProperty('--side-panel-width', value + 'px'); // OR CHANGE CUSTOM PROPERTY
         )
       }
```

Please, can you explain why is this performance issue happening and is there a way to solve it while not changing width directly?

UPD:

- I simplified my code for event handler in order to make it more essential
- I applied `will-change: width;` CSS property to `.side-panel` too

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change css variable, first thing you wanna do is to select the `:root`:

```
const root = document.querySelector(':root');
```

then

```
root.style.setProperty('--side-panel-width', value + 'px');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your response!

There's no problem to select root at all, i just skipped it to simplify this code snippet. Style is applied correctly, but still freezing :(